# Cannot use unicode shortcut on non-english layouts

Tags: keyboard, unicode, input

I’m using US and RU layouts, and while I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, when I have US layout selected, when I try to use it with RU layout selected, it just doesn’t work. Didn’t find anything related to it in settings, including Input Devices > Keyboard > Advanced.

How can I use this shortcut on RU layout or maybe there are other shortcuts?

The reason I want this is that I sometimes need characters like `#` that are just not present on RU layout and switching back and forth just gets very annoying.

I'm on Manjaro 6.0, KDE

Comment: Please clarify your question, for example at what operating system you try this...